# conditional 'and' in where clause depending existing value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

Can anybody knows if I could use a "conditional 'and' in where clause" depending of an existing value??,  I have a query like this:

```
@declare idProduct int = 1,
@declare idProducType int = null

select 
    tbl.idProduct, tbl.idProductType, tbl.ProductName, tbl.ProductPrice 
from MyTable tbl 
where tbl.idProduct = 1 
    <IF idProductType is not null>
        and tbl.idProductType = SOMEVALUE
    <ELSE>
        do nothing
    <ENDIF>
```

I require get data from this query always instead of getting null values when condition is false. how I can do like this in SQL Server 2008 ???

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
select 
tbl.idProduct, tbl.idProductType, tbl.ProductName, tbl.ProductPrice 
from MyTable tbl 
where tbl.idProduct = 1 and (tbl.idProductType = @idProducType or @idProducType is null)
```

Comment: I deleted my comment since there is no join occuring here (I misread the query) so in this case, neither ordering will necessarily be more optimal than the other.  (It would depend on the distribution of null/not-null values in that column; your query is more optimal if there are more non-null values.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@declare idProduct int = 1,
@declare idProducType int = null

SELECT
    tbl.idProduct, tbl.idProductType, tbl.ProductName, tbl.ProductPrice 
FROM MyTable tbl 
WHERE tbl.idProduct = 1 
    AND (CASE WHEN idProductType is not null THEN tbl.idProductType = SOMEVALUE
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
....
where tbl.idProduct = 1 
  and (CASE WHEN idProductType is not null and tbl.idProductType = SOMEVALUE Then <something> END) = <something>
/
```